# “You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device", other posts didn't work for me

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I looked at many other links and stackoverflow posts but nothing fixed my problem, I installed my app through android studio and I deleted it after I turned off developer mode, now when I try to install it from the google play store it tells me “You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device”, I tried to open the app list that shows the apps in alphabetical order but it wasn't there, I tried to access the app list from storage but the app wasn't there either. I tried to install it again from android studio (I turned developer mode on again) but the app wouldn't install, I got an error that says there's no MainActivity but I'm able to run the app through android studio on other devices.

What else can I do to completely delete the app from my phone and finally be able to download it from the Google Play Store?

Comment: Do you have multiple users present in you phone ? If so then app may have got installed in other users profile

Comment: ADB or Android Studio installs the package for all users by default. If you uninstall it in Settings UI, it's uninstalled from your current user profile only, but still left on the device for other users. Use ADB to uninstall the package for all users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use adb (android debug bridge). It's included with android studio SDK tools.

Just find your installation folder and run in cmd

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

This will list all the packages installed on your phone. If your package is listed then its installed. Then to uninstall it

```
adb shell pm uninstall YourPackageName
```

If there are any issues it will return an error.